# Alternating series variant of a convergent series

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence, absolute-convergence

I'm trying to prove whether the following series is convergent, divergent, or that there is not enough info.

If the series ∑ a<sub>n</sub> is convergent and has positive terms, what is the series below?

$$ \sum{(-1)^na_n}$$

I know that the series a_n is absolutely convergent, so the alternating one should be convergent, but I"m not sure how to prove it. The limit of a<sub>n</sub> as n goes to infinity is 0, so a<sub>n</sub> should be decreasing eventually, so it should be convergent by the Alternating Series Test.

Comment: Leibnitz theorem proves that

Comment: Use $\Bigl|\sum_{n=k}^{k+m} (-1)^n a_n\Bigr|\le \sum_{n=k}^{k+m}|a_n|$.

Comment: Thanks, David, that works!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The general rule is that if $\sum|x_n|$ converges, then $\sum x_n$ converges. This is a simple application of that fact.

Answer (score 0):

By the convergence of $\sum_0^\infty a_k$, the sequence $(s_n)$, where $s_n=\sum_0^n (-1)^k a_k$ is a Cauchy sequence.

Proof: If $m\lt n$, then $|s_n-s_m|\le a_{m+1}+\cdots +a_n$.

Comment: I haven't studied Cauchy sequences, is there another way to do this?

Comment: @ElectronicGeek If you know about absolute convergence, you should have studied Cauchy sequences, since usually they're what you use to prove that absolute convergence implies convergence.

Comment: One can get it from Bolzano-Weierstrass.